# Why does the compiler try to instantiate the wrong STL template? (BinaryOperation instead of UnaryOperation)

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I want to use `std::transform` with a parallel execution policy. The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) tells to use the template (2):

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy,
          class ForwardIt1,
          class ForwardIt2,
          class UnaryOperation >
ForwardIt2 transform( ExecutionPolicy&& policy,
                      ForwardIt1 first1,
                      ForwardIt1 last1,
                      ForwardIt2 d_first,
                      UnaryOperation unary_op );
```

My code is as follows, and seems to match the template:

```
const std::vector<SimulatedBody>& bodies = m_data.back().m_bodies;
std::vector<SimulatedBody> updated_bodies;
std::transform(std::execution::par,
    bodies.begin(),
    bodies.end(),
    std::back_inserter(updated_bodies),
    [&](const SimulatedBody& body) {
        return body.updated(*quadtree, m_dt, m_force_algorithm_fn);
    });
```

The return type of `body.updated` is a new `SimulatedBody`:

```
SimulatedBody SimulatedBody::updated(
    const bh::Node& quadtree, float dt,
    const std::function<Vector2d(const Node&, const Body&)>&
        force_algorithm_fn = bh::compute_approximate_net_force_on_body) const
```

However, when I compile, it raises the following error:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/12/../../../../include/c++/12/pstl/glue_algorithm_impl.h:325:44: error: argument may not have 'void' type
        [__op](_InputType __x, _OutputType __y) mutable { __y = __op(__x); },
                                           ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation/simple_simulator.cpp:35:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::transform<const __pstl::execution::parallel_policy &, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const bh::SimulatedBody *, std::vector<bh::SimulatedBody>>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<bh::SimulatedBody>>, (lambda at /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation/simple_simulator.cpp:37:18)>' requested here
  std::transform(std::execution::par, bodies.begin(), bodies.end(),
       ^
```

From the error, it seems that the compiler it is trying to use the wrong template; in particular, one with a BinaryOperation.

Am I missing something?

I am using gcc version 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1).

Comment: What's the return type of `SimulatedBody::updated`?

Comment: Its a brand new SimulatedBody. I edited the question including the function signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My code [...] seems to match the template:

It doesn't:

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy,
          class ForwardIt1,
          class ForwardIt2,
          class UnaryOperation >
ForwardIt2 transform( ExecutionPolicy&& policy,
                      ForwardIt1 first1,
                      ForwardIt1 last1,
                      ForwardIt2 d_first, // < here
                      UnaryOperation unary_op );
```

In the [*Parameters*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform#Parameters) section, the documentation you linked specifies the beginning of the destination range, parameter `d_first`, should be a forward iterator:

> **Type requirements**
>
> - [...]
> - `ForwardIt1`, `ForwardIt2`, `ForwardIt3` must meet the requirements of LegacyForwardIterator.

You're passing it an output iterator, i.e.:

```
std::back_inserter(updated_bodies)
```

---

If `SimulatedBody` is default constructible, you may resize `updated_bodies` to the size of `bodies` and pass `updated_bodies.begin()` (which is a random-access iterator, hence a forward iterator too) to `std::transform`:

```
const std::vector<SimulatedBody>& bodies = m_data.back().m_bodies;
std::vector<SimulatedBody> updated_bodies;
updated_bodies.resize(bodies.size()); // Resize output vector
std::transform(std::execution::par,
    bodies.begin(),
    bodies.end(),
    updated_bodies.begin(), // Pass iterator to first element
    [&](const SimulatedBody& body) {
        return body.updated(*quadtree, m_dt, m_force_algorithm_fn);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I am a C++ beginner, so I have one further question, if I may. In my application logic, `SimulatedBody` represents an "immutable" data structure: it has a parametrized constructor which initializes two `const` fields, which are not intended to vary. Therefore, it is not default constructible, and is not assignable. I may define a default constructor and make the field non-`const`, but it's a bit "ugly". Am I obliged to make this concession in order to make `transform` work, or is there another way around the problem?

Comment: I'd make the member variables private and non-`const`; and provide only public `const` getters to them. This allows you to keep your code `const` correct and implement a default constructor and a copy (or move) assignment operator for `SimulatedBody`. However, I suggest you ask another question providing more details regarding this issue so that you can collect more informed and pertinent answers.